# flex 3 number input validation on text field (restrict range to 1-100)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

On an Adobe Photoshop Panel (uses Flex 3) I have several text fields that take numerical input like this:

```
<mx:TextInput x="90" y="10" width="50" height="20" restrict="0-9" id="myInput"/>
```

I have the `restrict="0-9"` that keeps the user from entering anything but numbers however I'd like to restrict the range to 1-100.

Should I implement that myself using a change event handler in AS3 or is there a better solution with what Flex brings with it?

I tried this:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:NumberValidator source="{myInput}" property="text" integerError="Enter Integer value"
            minValue="1" maxValue="100" domain="int" 
            trigger="{myInput}" triggerEvent="change"
            invalid="myInput='50';"/>
</fx:Declarations>
```

but I get `Error: Could not resolve <fx:Declarations> to a component implementation.`

Comment: There are many options. Flex has validator components you can use like the [NumberValidator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/NumberValidator.html). It works well in conjunction with a `<mx:Form>`, but you can also use them in your own change event handler. Aside from these two approaches and the `restrict` property that you're already using, there's no shortcuts to restricting the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [NumericStepper](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NumericStepper.html) instead of a TextInput.  Then you can set the [minimum](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/Range.html#minimum) and [maximum](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NumericStepper.html#maximum) values.

```
<s:NumericStepper id="ns" minimum="1" maximum="100" />
```

Update: 
In Flex 3; you can use the MX Numeric Stepper with similar properties:

```
<mx:NumericStepper id="ns" minimum="1" maximum="100" stepSize="1"/>
```

Comment: is that route available without spark which does not exist in Flex3?

Comment: <mx:NumericStepper id="ns" minimum="1" maximum="100" stepSize="1"/>

Comment: Yep; sorry I missed the Flex 3 requirement.  Glad you found the answer regardless.